# condition is not working in less

Tags: css, less

I tried to change the existing padding values using less but it's not working. Is is my way is correct? pls suggest.

It is like toggle function. If padding value is 20px, I have to change 0px and same as 0px to 20px.

**LESS:**

```
.add, .toggle {
    padding: 8px 20px 8px 20px;
    .theme("20px");
    &:hover {
        padding: 8px 18px 8px 18px;
      .themed("18px");
    }
    &:active {
        padding: 8px 18px 8px 18px;
      .themed("18px");
    }
    &:focus {
        padding: 8px 18px 8px 18px;
      .themed("18px");
    }
}
.theme (@mode) when (@mode = "20px") {
  padding: 8px 0px 8px 20px;
}
.themed (@mode) when (@mode = "18px") {
  padding: 8px 0px 8px 18px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Your mixins](http://less2css.org/#%7B%22less%22%3A%22.add%2C%20.toggle%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20padding%3A%208px%2020px%208px%2020px%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20.theme(%5C%2220px%5C%22)%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%26%3Ahover%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20padding%3A%208px%2018px%208px%2018px%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20.themed(%5C%2218px%5C%22)%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%7D%5Cn%20%20%20%20%26%3Aactive%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20padding%3A%208px%2018px%208px%2018px%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20.themed(%5C%2218px%5C%22)%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%7D%5Cn%20%20%20%20%26%3Afocus%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20padding%3A%208px%2018px%208px%2018px%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20.themed(%5C%2218px%5C%22)%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%7D%5Cn%7D%5Cn.theme%20(%40mode)%20when%20(%40mode%20%3D%20%5C%2220px%5C%22)%20%7B%5Cn%20%20padding%3A%208px%200px%208px%2020px%3B%5Cn%7D%5Cn.themed%20(%40mode)%20when%20(%40mode%20%3D%20%5C%2218px%5C%22)%20%7B%5Cn%20%20padding%3A%208px%200px%208px%2018px%3B%5Cn%7D%22%7D) with the conditions work fine for me, they're overriding the padding, by adding another padding definition. Sample (not complete) CSS output:

```
.add,
.toggle {
  padding: 8px 20px 8px 20px;
  padding: 8px 0px 8px 20px; /* this takes effect */
}
/* ... */
```

If it does not seem to work, you can try to add `!important` before `;` inside the mixins.

---

But you can do the LESS code simpler, with one mixin, and by using `@mode` [parameter inside the rule](http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-parametric-feature):

```
.add, .toggle {
  .theme(20px); // <-- no quotes

  &:hover, &:active, &:focus { // <-- merged them as they're the same
    .theme(18px); // <-- no quotes
  }
}

.theme (@mode) {
  padding: 8px 0px 8px @mode; // <-- use parameter
}
```

Notice I removed the quotes too from mixin calls. You can [see it working here](http://less2css.org/#%7B%22less%22%3A%22.add%2C%20.toggle%20%7B%5Cn%20%20.theme(20px)%3B%20%2F%2F%20%3C--%20no%20quotes%5Cn%5Cn%20%20%26%3Ahover%2C%20%26%3Aactive%2C%20%26%3Afocus%20%7B%20%2F%2F%20%3C--%20merged%20them%20as%20they're%20the%20same%5Cn%20%20%20%20.theme(18px)%3B%20%2F%2F%20%3C--%20no%20quotes%5Cn%20%20%7D%5Cn%7D%5Cn%5Cn.theme%20(%40mode)%20%7B%5Cn%20%20padding%3A%208px%200px%208px%20%40mode%3B%20%2F%2F%20%3C--%20use%20parameter%5Cn%7D%22%7D), it produces (effectively) the same CSS output as your code.

Hope I could help.